# Replace values in a list based on condition of previous value

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to modify a list that has 3 different numbers [0, 1, 2]

Each 0 should be replaced with either the last 1 or 2 value depending on which was most recent during the iteration.

Is it possible to create the new list using a list comprehension?

I know I can use a for loop and just record the last 1 or 2 and append the values to the new list but I prefer the most pythonic way.

`list = [1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0]`

`new_list = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]`

I was using this but then realised that after 2 0s in a sequence it would start recording 0s again.

```
new_list = [list[index-1] if list[index] == 0 else value for index,value in enumerate(list)]
```

Comment: LCs aren't really that great at keeping state. Can you show your existing solution so we have a point of reference? Thanks.

Comment: You can probably implement this using Python 3.9's "walrus operator" but it would be obfuscated and not more Pythonic than the `for` loop method.

Comment: should be rather straightforward just loop over the list and remember the last 'valid' [1 or 2] entry, if you encounter a zero replace with the last valid entry. If current 'valid' entry is different update. Just watch out for the edge case where first entry is a zero... Show us your solution for comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting in python 3.8 you now have the walrus operator `:=` which can assign values as part of an expression and works in list comprehensions. You just need to decide what the first value will be if the list starts with `0` since there is no previous value:

```
alist = [1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0]

j = 0
[j:= i if i else j for i in alist]
# [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Looks good, I'll give this a try. The first value can be a zero.

Comment: until a first 1 or 2 (or any non zero number) is encountered the elements will be zero. But if you want you can give it any value for example  by setting `j = False`.

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen yes, thank you. Until you get a non zero value "the last" isn't clearly defined.

Answer (score 2):

Perform that just with a list comprehension could be a little weird, so here my solution (without creating a new list):

```
my_list = [1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0]
last_not_zero = 0

for index, number in enumerate(my_list):
    if number!=0:
        last_not_zero = number
    else:
        my_list[index] = last_not_zero

print(my_list)
```

And you'll get:
[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]

Comment: This is good also but not sure it would be more efficient than a standard for loop of the list. It saves you having to create a new_list however.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large list or you are using Pandas in your code,

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(list)
s.replace(0, pd.np.nan).ffill().to_list()
```

Output

```
[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

**NOTE: If you are not using pandas/numpy in your code, then basic for loop would be the best way to do this. Advise using the above code only for large arrays with multiple manipulations.**

Comment: Good suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
last_value = 0
new_list = []
for value in list:
    if value != 0:
        last_value = value
        new_list.append(value)
    else:
        new_list.append(last_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the condition.
In most cases, you can place the condition within the while loop in the if-else criteria statements.

If, say, you want to replace the content of a list if the previous value was
something,

```
size = len(list)
while True:
    index = index + 1
    if index!=0 and index<size:
        if list[index-1]==something:
            list[index] = value to be replaced
        if index == (size-1):
            a = 0
            for a in (0, (size-1)):
                print(a,":",list(a))
            break
```